# how to implement add expression for date in drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

When i try to use timestamp in time format in expression .I got error

For example

```
$query->addExpression('date("H:i:s","dept_timestamp")','time_val');
```

Comment: "dept_timestamp" is a string. perhaps you mean `$dept_timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've put a PHP function into addExpression. It's feeding your expression straight into the database, so you'll want to use a date-formatting function that your db will understand. Assuming you're using MySQL as a backend, you'd want something like this:

```
$query->addExpression('from_unixtime("dept_timestamp", "%h:%i:%s")', 'time_val');
```

Here's a full example that, for no good reason, joins the node table and the field_data_body table:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
$query->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'n.nid = b.entity_id');
$query->fields('b', array('body_value'));
$query->addExpression("from_unixtime(created, '%h:%i:%s')", 'my_timestamp');
$result = $query->execute();
```